# django1.8 cannot include css, js files in template

Tags: html, css, django, static, django-1.8

I created a "testproject" using django 1.8. The CSS, JS, Images are not working. I included template, css and js folder outside project folder like this:

My project folder is : `/home/myuser/testproject/`
My media folder is : `/var/www/test_media/`
                                  template (folder)
                                  css (folder)
                                  js (folder)

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = '#tg20j5v6odye)p*pd9u=+^1xybqlmicvuq+#&m*&c(dcuk6n)'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/var/www/test_media/template'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/test_media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'test_media/'
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}css/style.css">
  <script src='{{MEDIA_URL}}jquery/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="{{MEDIA_URL}}js/index.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TEST PROJECT</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Welcome </h1>
        <form class="form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
        </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
def logIn(request):
      return render_to_response("index.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Curious, Why do you kept those files outside the folder?

Comment: Please remove that exception handler. Django will provide a useful error page, but you're preventing it from doing so.

Comment: @vaibhav I just want to keep the project files and all media files seperately. If I keep media inside the project ,its looks like complicated..

Comment: @DanielRoseman removed exception handler.. but what I need is to include css,js files in my html

Comment: are you able to see anything if u visit `127.0.0.1:8000/test_media/css/style.css`

Comment: I got the media files !!.. I added       STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                                                              os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
                                                              '/var/www/test_media/',
                                                           )     in settings.py &   in index.html    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" >
 <script src="{% static "jquery/jquery.js" %}"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the media files !!.. I added in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),  
                    '/var/www/test_media/', )
```

& changed in index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" >  
<script src="{% static "jquery/jquery.js" %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup and use the static files by first setting STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS to say where the files are and should go

Comment: `collectstatic` is for deployment, you shouldn't need to use it in the development setup

Comment: (edited) correct, but still need to setup the static files fully

Comment: It looks like my answer was correct? If setting the STATICFILES_DIRS fixed it?